# Why does my app work with app actions test tool, but not when it's published on the play store?

Tags: android, google-assistant, app-actions

I've been trying to get app actions to work for my app but it only ever seems to work when I use the app actions test tool. When my app is published to the play store none of my phrases that worked in the app actions test tool work with google assistant. If someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong here that would be very helpful.

actions.xml:

```
<actions>
    <action intentName="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE">
        <fulfillment urlTemplate="{@url}" />

        <!-- Define parameters with inventories here -->
        <parameter name="feature">
            <entity-set-reference entitySetId="featureParamEntitySet"/>
        </parameter>
    </action>
    <entity-set entitySetId="featureParamEntitySet">
        <entity url="https://myapp.com/startmyapp" name="open my app" alternateName="@array/startMyAppSynonyms"/>
        <entity url="https://myapp.com/stopmyapp" name="close my app" alternateName="@array/stopMyAppSynonyms"/>
    </entity-set>
</actions>
```

arrays.xml:

```
<resources>
    <array name="startMyAppSynonyms">
        <item>turn on</item>
        <item>activate</item>
        <item>on</item>
        <item>signal on</item>
    </array>

    <array name="stopMyAppSynonyms">
        <item>turn off</item>
        <item>deactivate</item>
        <item>off</item>
        <item>signal off</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

Comment: App Actions go through a [review process](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/get-started#request-review) before availability in production.  Are you sure that the review process completed successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my app was just waiting to be reviewed and published.